# StackView not shrinking when removing arranged subview

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a vertical stackview with 7 subviews. When I remove one of the subviews the stack view doesnt shrink, but the view above the removed view occupies the freed space.

I have tried

`subview.isHidden = true`

as well as

```
stackview.removeArrangedSubview(subview)
subview.removeFromSuperView()
```

Should the stackview automatically shrink by pushing all subviews below the removed subview upwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it won't shrink , but when you set

```
subview.isHidden = true
```

the other views occupy the freed space if you set `distribution` to `fillEqually` , if you want it to shrink then hook the height constraint of it and in addition to the above line do

```
stackH.constant = numberOfRemainingSubviews * viewHeight
```

Comment: sorry to bother I've created this chatroom [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177811/stackview-discussion). Can you jump in?